# Python not allowing variables in input

Tags: python, input, python-3.6

In Python 3.6 when entering the code

```
var = 1
var1 = input("Hey var = ",(var),"Bye : ")
```

for some reason it comes out with an error message

```
    var1 = input("Hey var = ",(var),"Bye : ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments got 1/2/3/4/5/6+
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so it runs like:

```
Hey var = 1 Bye : (where you enter text)
```

Comment: *For some reason"* - because you're passing more than the one argument it expects, as the message tells you. Maybe make the prompt string first? `input('Hey var = {} Bye :'.format(var))`, for example.

Comment: Awesome thanks. bphi. Can you make that an answer so i cant close this. Also what is the "f" for at the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` expects a string as an argument so you can't pass it multiple args like with `print`. Instead you can [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) the string before you pass it to `input`:

```
var = 1
var1 = input(f"Hey var = {var} Bye : ")
```

The `f` before the string is short for format and is new in Python 3.6, you can read more about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Comment: I believe that f before "Hey ..." is a typo.

Comment: @JosephRyle you believe wrong - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: If u can, could you tell me what the "f" is for

Comment: @Matt see my comment above, or just *run it and see*

Comment: Ah, Python 3.6. That explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I might not answer your question fully but you can't have more than one argument in `input()`.

```
var = 1
var1 = input("Enter something:")
print(f"Hey {var} Bye : {var1}")
```